# ExpressionEngine 2, admin path routing

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, expressionengine

My first day with ExpressionEngine, I know basic CodeIgniter.

1. **./admin.php** renamed to **./john_doe.php**
2. updated the **$config['cp_url']** value to `http://mysite.com/john_doe.php`

I want to redirect *mysite.com/**johndoe*** to *mysite.com/**john_doe.php***, just for an alternative to administrate EE2.

In CodeIgniter (according to user guide) this line must be added into **./application/config/routes.php** file:

```
$route['johndoe'] = "john_doe.php";
```

The question is: How can I do this in ExpressionEngine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This won't help your problem at all but I found that serious in depth knowledge of code igniter did not help me at all when I had to deal with EE. Might as well be forgotten that it has anything to do with CI at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is redirect `/johndoe` to `/john_doe.php`, you don't need to do anything with ExpressionEngine (unless you really want to).

Instead, just create a simple `mod_rewrite` rule in Apache's `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^johndoe /john_doe.php [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It used to be difficult to [mask access to the Control Panel](http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/installation/masked_cp_access.html) in EE1, but as of EE 2.2 it's simple — simply rename the included file `admin.php` to whatever you'd like.

Then use that filename in your URL to access the Control Panel instead of the [renamed] system folder:

```
http://example.com/Xtr3m-H4x0r.php
```

ExpressionEngine will rewrite all of its Control Panel links to use the *masked access* filename -- just don't forget to edit the file to make sure the path to your system folder is set correctly:

```
$system_path = './renamed-system-folder';
```

Comment: Although the .htaccess file solution failed I prefer the rename-file solution and give a complex name and the right path to the CP file.

Comment: I just fixed the `.htaccess` rule by removing the beginning slash on the URI; complete oversight on my part. It should work correctly now.

Answer (score 1):

The "old school" — à la EE1 — way to mask access to the Control Panel in EE2 is still possible.

Open up `/system/index.php` and uncomment `define('MASKED_CP', TRUE);`:

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  MASKED CP ACCESS
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This lets the system know whether or not the control panel is being
 * accessed from a location outside the system folder
 * 
 * NOTE: If you set this, be sure that you set the $system_path and the 
 * 'cp_url' item in the $assign_to_config array below!
 * 
 */

 define('MASKED_CP', TRUE);
```

In the same file, uncomment and set the following two variables to your new environment:

```
$system_path = "./masked-system";

$assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'http://example.com/masked-system/index.php';
```

This is yet another way to *mask access to the Control Panel*.

The technique of renaming `admin.php` is far easier and and is recommended as a [**Post-Installation Best Practice**](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/installation/best_practices.html) in the ExpressionEngine User Guide.

Comment: A lot of tries and didn't work as expected but is an interesting solution to the way I wanted to resolve it.